# Perl Mojolicious: handling proxy timeouts

Tags: docker, apache, perl, promise, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious App behind a reverse proxy. The Mojo App uses [Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916916/perl-mojolicious-chaining-promises), and in some cases, the synchronous response is returned after 2 minutes, by which time, the reverse proxy times out.

How can I best render the response? (making my subroutine respond sooner, unfortunately, is not an option)

- Can I show a temporary page, but commit / render the final response afterwards?
- Can I use Ajax to show a *spinner*, then render the final response once done?
- Should I switch to Async, perhaps integrate Mojolicious with Minion, and render a response that checks if the async call is ready via Ajax? (pointers and samples would be appreciated).

I demonstrate this behavior using `docker` below with a reverse proxy that times out after 5 seconds, and a mojo app that responds after 10 seconds:

#### 1. Create a `Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.io/library/perl:5.36
# Install Apache2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apache2
# Install Mojolicious
RUN cpanm Mojolicious
# Install Apache mod_proxy and configure Apache2 as a reverse proxy to mojo app with 5s timeout
RUN a2enmod proxy_http \
    && perl -i.bak -pe 's#</VirtualHost>#\tProxyPass /mojo http://localhost:3000/ keepalive=On timeout=5\n</VirtualHost>#' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
# Generate a mojo app and simulate a timer
RUN mojo generate app \
    && perl -i.bak -pe 's/^.*$/  sleep(10);/ if $. == 6' /my_app/lib/MyApp/Controller/Example.pm
# Expose Apache2 and Mojo ports
EXPOSE 80 3000
# Run Apache 2 in the background and Morbo in the foreground
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "apache2ctl start; /my_app/script/my_app prefork"]
```

#### 2. Build & run:

```bash
docker build -t myapp .
docker run --rm --name myapp -p 8080:80 -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

#### 3. Browse to:

```
http://localhost:8080/mojo
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103802/apache-reverseproxy-timeouts-exactly-after-60-secs

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500. The solution provided suggests increasing the reverse proxy timeout, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with an asynchronous approach using [Minion](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Minion) as a queue. A full working example of a `LinkCheck` application is provided at:

https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/tree/main/examples/linkcheck

The example requires you either:

1. Start a Postgres Database, for example using `docker`:

```bash
docker run --rm --name postgres -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -p 5432:5432 postgres:15
```

OR
2. [Replace one line during startup](https://github.com/mojolicious/minion/blob/36b9a75918b1fc4128b6bade756d9afd8c28d649/examples/linkcheck/lib/LinkCheck.pm#L14) to use SQLite instead of Postgres. (requires [`Minion::Backend::SQLite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion::Backend::SQLite) plugin )

```perl
$self->plugin(Minion => {SQLite=>'sqlite:minion.db'});
```

In either cases, you must run a [separate a background worker process to handle the job queue](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Minion/Guide#Mojolicious), for example:

```bash
perl script/linkcheck minion worker
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at a streaming response, and writing chunks of your response as you they are built, rather than sending them after the whole response is built, see https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Streaming

Comment: Thanks @roger. Would you kindly share a working example or link to a useful one? I wonder how the browser/CSS will render partial content... interesting nonetheless. Thank you!